# config transformation in docker

Tags: configuration, docker

We are currently working on migrating our Sitecore solution to docker. Earlier we were utilizing octopus for config transformation between CD and CM server roles and variable replacement between environments. In Octopus config transformation happens only during deployment, based on the conditional statements like the snippet below. But this cannot be used with docker, so we would like to understand the best approach for config transformation between CM / CD / Standalone server roles.

```
#{if isLB}
#{if isCM}
#{if isSTGPROD}
<!-- deploysecondary -->
<database id="deploysecondary" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel">
  <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
  <icon>Images/database_web.png</icon>
  <securityEnabled>true</securityEnabled>
  <dataProviders hint="list:AddDataProvider">
    <dataProvider ref="dataProviders/main" param1="$(id)">
      <disableGroup>publishing</disableGroup>
      <prefetch hint="raw:AddPrefetch">
        <sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Common.config"/>
        <sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Webdb.config"/>
      </prefetch>
    </dataProvider>
  </dataProviders>
```

Comment: Maybe https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/rule-based-configuration.html

Comment: @MarekMusielak thank you, it looks like, this is the only suitable option we could use.

Comment: comment converted into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rule-based configuration.

Read more about it https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/rule-based-configuration.html

How does it work? You put all your Sitecore configs in `App_Config/Include` folder of all your Sitecore instances but additionally you define role of every environment in web.config in `<AppSettings>` section, e.g.

```
<add key="role:define" value="ContentManagement" />
```

Then add `role:require="ContentManagement"` your config, e.g.:

```
<configuration xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <sitecore role:require="ContentManagement">
      ...
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

That config part will be only used on `ContentManagement` role.

Another useful link: https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2017/10/17/rules-based-configuration/